# Customizing Chrome Tab Bar

Tags: google-chrome, touchscreen, google-chrome-extensions

I have a touch screen monitor, which does not sense touch well around the edges of the monitor.

I use google chrome as my web browser, and its hard to click on the tabs (because they are at the very top of the screen when Chrome is maximized).

What I would like to do is either:

- 1)  Enlarge the Tabs/Tab-Bar  (The
  bigger the better)
- 2)  Move the tab
  bar to below the address area (like
  where it is in Firefox)

Any extensions, hacks, customizations that allow this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the tabs to the side:

[image: configure-side-tabs]

---

[image: set-side-tabs]

---

[image: voilà -side-tabs]

**Caveat:** Requires Chrome dev edition & side tabs need to be enabled from `chrome://labs/` page

Answer (score 0):

[OneTab](http://www.one-tab.com/) for Chrome maybe helpful in this instance:

Whenever you find yourself with too many tabs, click the OneTab icon to convert all of your tabs into a list. When you need to access the tabs again, you can either restore them individually or all at once.

When your tabs are in the OneTab list, you will save up to 95% of memory because you will have reduced the number of tabs open in Google Chrome.

Whilst it doesn't accomplish exactly what you require, it does make accessing your tabs considerably easier than what you currently have or had.